# Linux disconnect two subnetworks

Tags: nat, router, forwarding, subnets

I have one router with 3 networkcards (one goes global and two are intern) and I would like to know if i enabled in the router nat.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 so does a host on subnet 1 cann reach a host on subnet 2 ?

If so how can I disable both subnetwork from seeing each other but still reaching global internet.

I'm using Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, usually in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and enabling it will allow the router to route from any network to any other unless there are restrictions in place.

The simplest way to achieve the restrictions you want would be using `iptables` FORWARD rules.

For example, if the network interface for subnet 1 is `eno1` and for subnet 2 `eno2` respectively, you might add these two iptables rules in the very beginning of the FORWARD ruleset:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eno1 -o eno2 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -i eno2 -o eno1 -j DROP
```

Translation:

- rule #1 for forwarding packets: if the packet came in `eno1` and would be going out via `eno2`, DROP it.
- rule #2 for forwarding packets: if the packet came in `eno2` and would be going out via `eno1`, DROP it.

Since you did not specify the Linux distribution you're using in the router, the problem of integrating these basic-form `iptables` rules to any higher-level firewall management tool you might have (`firewalld`, `ufw`, many others) must be left as an exercise for the reader.